# xPath select Svg parent of node

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have this html code :

```
<button>
    <svg aria-label="Options">
        <circle></circle>
    </svg>
</button>
```

I need to select the button to click it like this :

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//svg[@aria-label="Options"]/parent::button').click()
```

I've also tried this :

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('..//button/svg[@aria-label="Options"]').click()
```

But it says :

> NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"..."}

How to select this button please ? I cannot show the all code, the button is not reachable easily because it has random classes... Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the xpath that you can use.

```
//*[@aria-label='Options'][name()='svg']/parent::button
```

[image]

Comment: Probably because a specific namespace has been declared.